# How can I make a gradual output of database

Tags: mysql, ajax

Lets suppose i have some records in the mysql, and i want to make the records output gradual, i mean for example:

in the begining outputs 2-4 records to the page, then when i scroll down new records appends on the page, but the previus records that stays at the top are dissapearing, this way i want to replace the classic pagination, is this possible to do??

and please can you tell me some JQuery methods that can be usefull for this task?? and some tricks to combine??

i think that here i need to use ajax yes?

i am doing something like this the first time.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will certainly need ajax for this. I would recommend listening for when the user has scrolled past a certain point using `$(window).scrollTop()` and then issuing your ajax request from there.

You will want to make sure to keep track of how many records you have already loaded (for your LIMIT statements in future queries) and the Y position of when you want the scroll to trigger the data loading.